# Sobre blockchain: no se muestran todos los bloques creados

Tags: java, blockchain

estoy creando una blockchain con sus bloques y demas, y estoy teniendo un problema a la hora de listar todos los bloques creados en mi clase Blockchain. Al parecer la variable blocks no esta añadadiendo el bloque correctamente al listado y no entiendo porque.

**BlockChain**

```
public class Blockchain {

  static ArrayList<Block> blocks;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
       
        blocks= new ArrayList<>(); // Create an ArrayList object
        Blockchain blockchain = new Blockchain(new MemoryPool(), new Wallet());
        blockchain.addBlock("data1");
        blockchain.addBlock("data2");
        blockchain.addBlock("data3");
        blockchain.verBloques();

    }

    MemoryPool memorypool;
    Wallet blockchainWallet;

    public Blockchain(MemoryPool memoryPool, Wallet wallet) {

        blocks.add(genesis());
        this.memorypool = new MemoryPool();
        this.blockchainWallet = new Wallet();
    }
    
    public Block addBlock(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        Block previousBlock = blocks.get(blocks.size() - 1);
        Block block = Block.mine(previousBlock, data);
        blocks.add(block);
        return block;
    }

    public void verBloques() {
        for (int i = 0; i < blocks.size()-1; i++) {
            System.out.println(blocks.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Por otro lado, aqui esta la clase Block, que si funciona correctamente.

```
public class Block {

    static int dificultad = 3;
    static long timestamp;
    static String previoushash;
    static String hash;
    static String data;
    static int nonce;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        Block uno = mine(genesis(), "datos");
        System.out.println(uno);

        Block dos = mine(uno, "datos2");
        System.out.println(dos);

        Block tres = mine(dos, "datos3");
        System.out.println(tres);

        Block cuatro = mine(tres, "datos4");
        System.out.println(cuatro);

        Block cinco = mine(cuatro, "datos5");
        System.out.println(cinco);
        // Block tres= mine(dos,"datos3");

        //  System.out.println(tres);
    }

    public Block(long timestamp, String previoushash, String hash, String data, int nonce, int dificultad) {
        this.dificultad = dificultad;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.previoushash = previoushash;
        this.hash = hash;
        this.data = data;
        this.nonce = nonce;

    }

    static Block genesis() {

        timestamp = new Date(2010, 0, 1).getTime();
        previoushash = "g3n3s1s-h4sh";
        data = "i like ramen";
        Block blockgenesis = new Block(timestamp, null, previoushash, data, 0, 3);
        return blockgenesis;
    }

    static Block mine(Block previousBlock, String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        String hashanterior = previousBlock.hash;
        String hash;
        long timestamp;
        int dificultad = previousBlock.dificultad;
        
        do{
            timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
            nonce++;
            dificultad =ajustarDificultad(previousBlock,timestamp);
            hash = Block.hash(timestamp, previousBlock.hash, data, nonce, dificultad);
        }while(!hash.substring(0,dificultad).equals("0".repeat(dificultad)));
        return new Block(timestamp, hashanterior, hash, data, nonce, dificultad);
    }

    static String hash(long timestamp, String previousHash, String data, int nonce, int dificultad) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        String text = "" + timestamp + "," + previousHash + "," + data + "," + nonce + "," + dificultad + "";

        // Change this to UTF-16 if needed
        md.update(text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] digest = md.digest();

        String hex = String.format("%064x", new BigInteger(1, digest));

        return hex;
    }

    static int RatioMinero = 3000;

    static int ajustarDificultad(Block bloqueprevio, long timestamp) {
        dificultad = bloqueprevio.dificultad;
        if (bloqueprevio.timestamp + RatioMinero > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            return dificultad + 1;
        } else {
            return dificultad - 1;
        }

    }

    Block() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); // Generated from nbfs://nbhost/SystemFileSystem/Templates/Classes/Code/GeneratedMethodBody
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        System.out.println("\nBlock:");
        System.out.println("timestamp: " + timestamp);
        System.out.println("previoushash: " + previoushash);
        System.out.println("hash: " + hash);
        System.out.println("data: " + data);
        System.out.println("nonce: " + nonce);
        System.out.println("dificultad: " + dificultad);
        return null;
    }

   

    

}
```

Un ejemplo de la salida de la clase Blockchain es este(podemos observar que se repite el mismo bloque):

Block:
timestamp: 1657531081370
previoushash: 000a7b2fdaad025959d095bf0df3bdd79d0c2dbfbddfadf314f835bbca636f1e
hash: 0000db5e676a8ebb6bf62e5c582250ace91266b172e72b2813fbb381a68f96e3
data: data3
nonce: 823699
dificultad: 4
null

Block:
timestamp: 1657531081370
previoushash: 000a7b2fdaad025959d095bf0df3bdd79d0c2dbfbddfadf314f835bbca636f1e
hash: 0000db5e676a8ebb6bf62e5c582250ace91266b172e72b2813fbb381a68f96e3
data: data3
nonce: 823699
dificultad: 4
null

Block:
timestamp: 1657531081370
previoushash: 000a7b2fdaad025959d095bf0df3bdd79d0c2dbfbddfadf314f835bbca636f1e
hash: 0000db5e676a8ebb6bf62e5c582250ace91266b172e72b2813fbb381a68f96e3
data: data3
nonce: 823699
dificultad: 4
null

Answer (score -2):

La solucion esta en cambiar todas las variables estaticas de la clase block por variables no estaticas.

Comment: Entendiste por qué?

Comment: La verdad es que no mucho, agradezco explicación

Comment: Por favor explica tu respuesta un poco más, siempre es bueno mencionar los motivos por los cuáles esa sería una solución viable

Comment: Por favor lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)